# Silverlight as a Front-end. What is the possible options for Back-end technology?

Tags: .net, database, silverlight, architecture

I want to create a web-portal (for managing hotel tasks), which should be accessible from the local network. As a Front-end technology I chose the Silverlight. On the back-end a some DBMS should be running and probably Entity Framework will be used. The question is, what are possible reasonable types of back-end application and how it would be reasonable to connect it with a client Silverlight application? Just don't want to create a bike, if there are any more or less standard designs.

Comment: You can use pretty much any server technology that you want. Of course, if you remain on the Microsoft stack, i.e. WCF, it might be easier. But as it is, your question has no objective answer.

Comment: options here pretty much up to your imagination; essentially "what can I use to write a web app (server-side)"

Comment: Of course, I am not asking for all theoretical possible options. I am sure the server side can be written even in assembler. I just was asking about best practices which usually works perfectly for Silverlight application (and maybe were created specially for using together with Silverlight). And it seems that WCF RIA Services is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common options would be [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)